# Align Title/Header with Text HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a centred div to contain an image and some text but want my title to have the same margin/alignment as the text. Right now the title is placed on the extreme left of the page and I want it to have a responsive margin on the left.

```css
.row {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Choosing a Console</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" id="textbox">
      <p>
        Some Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" id="img">
      <img style="height: 350px" src="which.png" alt="Which One">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a "responsive margin" exactly? How do you want it to resize?

Comment: If the problem is that the title and the text don't have the same left margin (as in the screenshot), you should prtovide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: So far as I'm aware Stack Snippets don't incorporate any CSS pre-, or post-, processors; so your CSS is invalid (and presents a problem that may not be an accurate representation of your site). Also, the `src` of the `<img>` element doesn't resolve, while the image itself doesn't matter it does complicate the question, given that you're asking about alignment. You could try to use a placeholder service ([placeholder.com](https://placeholder.com/) or [placekitten](https://placekitten.com/), for example) to supply appropriately-sized images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways you could do this;
Add margin-left to the div h2 tag or add a container

```css
.row {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 1150px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        img {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    
    .container-fluid h1 {
      margin-left: 150px;
    }
```

or you can over complicate it like I do and contain containers, I have added border outlines so you understand what that container is containing, if you wish to move the h1 and p text, you can margin-left them both.

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1150px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.rowTextContainer {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.rowText {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row img {
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="rowTextContainer">
    <div class="rowText">
      <h1>Title Text</h1>
      <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-sm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Choosing a Console</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" id="textbox">
      <p>
        Some Text go ahead . . . . .
      </p>
      <img style="height: 350px" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Which One">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will solve your problem.